# How to temporarily hide toolbar menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, toolbar

I have host activity which can have different fragments, it is some sort of `SingleFragmentActivity`, so user navigating between different fragments inside this activity, but inside my menu I have button that brings user to the another fragment, so I need to hide menu when fragment is replaced and restore it when user goes back to the previous fragment.
I have tried to clear menu, it works, but how can I restore menu than on previous fragment ?

In code this looks like

```
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mToolbarProvider = (ToolbarProvider) activity;
          //  mToolbarProvider.saveCurrentMenu();
            mToolbarProvider.getToolbar().getMenu().clear();

        }
        catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.error_tag), "Activty has to implement " + ToolbarProvider.class.getSimpleName() + " interface");
        }
    }
```

This work, but when I am back again to the fragment that needs menu, how can I restore menu, I have tried to save menu object, but doesn't work for me.

```
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mActivityController = (ActivityController) activity;
            mToolbarProvider = (ToolbarProvider) activity;
           /* Menu lastMenu = mToolbarProvider.restoreLastMenu();
            if(lastMenu!=null) {
                activity.onCreateOptionsMenu(lastMenu);
            }*/
            Menu toolBarMenu = mToolbarProvider.restoreLastMenu();
            if(toolBarMenu!=null) {
                mToolbarProvider.getToolbar().inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
            }

        } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.error_tag), "Activty has to implement " + ActivityController.class.getSimpleName() + " interface");
        }
    }
```

It would be better just to hide it and show when I need this.
Please help to implement this.

**EDIT**

As suggested below, I have tried to do this and first time it didn't work , but I have moved logic into `onCreateView` , I have really forgotten that I am doing everything in `onAttach`, that is called only once. Really stupid mistake.

So now everything works like a charm.
Here is code.
In `onCreateView()` in my fragment where I need to hide menu.

```
  Menu menu = mToolbarProvider.getToolbar().getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        if(menuItem!=null) {
            menuItem.setVisible(false);
            mToolbarProvider.addHiddenItem(menuItem);
        }
```

And in main fragment where all menu items are visible.

```
List<MenuItem> hiddenItemsList = mToolbarProvider.getAllHiddenItems();
    if(hiddenItemsList!=null && hiddenItemsList.size()>0) {
        int size = hiddenItemsList.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            hiddenItemsList.get(i).setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Or you create method like `setAllItemsVisible()`

Comment: you can try hide menu item by using `menuItem.setVisible(false);` and to show them again  `menuItem.setVisible(true);`

Comment: great !! please post your comment as answer !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try hide menu item by using `menuItem.setVisible(false);` and to show them again `menuItem.setVisible(true);`